# Moving files by terminal starting by a letter and finishing by a string

Tags: shell, glob

On MAC, I would like to move images from one directory to another, but not all the images only the images starting with IMG and ending with mobile
the starting folder is listed like this:

```
cd Download/images/

IMG001.jpg
IMG002.jpg
IMG003.jpg
IMG001_mobile.jpg
IMG002_mobile.jpg
IMG003_mobile.jpg
```

and the destination is on the desktop `Desktop/images`
and i want to have only

```
IMG001_mobile.jpg
IMG002_mobile.jpg
IMG003_mobile.jpg
```

Comment: something like `cd Download/images/ && mv *_mobile.jpg ../../Desktop/images`?

Comment: `mv -iv IMG*mobile.jpg Desktop/images`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `IMG` and ending with `mobile.jpg` is `IMG*mobile.jpg`, so you would do:

```
mv IMG*mobile.jpg Desktop/images
```